# Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit

Tags: java

Pre-note: This is not a problem I am having with Minecraft. All answers I can find seem to be related to Minecraft.

> Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I get this error when I try to do something Java related. I cannot launch a .jar without this error coming up and when I try to install JDK, I get this error. This has been plaguing me for a while and I was not able to research an answer so I thought I would ask it myself.

EDIT: Windows 7 (x64) Dell Studio Laptop, 4GB RAM, external Radeon HD 6950 Graphics Card. I have tried uninstalling all JVMs and reinstalling but it didn't work, although I cannot remember how thorough I was so I may try again. Here is a list of all the Java related things I have installed (found in the uninstall or change programs window):

- Java 3D 1.5.1
- Java 3D 1.5.1 (x64)
- Java 3D 1.5.2
- Java 6 Update 30
- Java 6 Update 30 (64-bit)
- Java 7 Update 2
- Java 7 Update 3 (64-bit)
- JavaFX 2.0.3 (64-bit)
- JavaFX 2.0.3 SDK (64-bit)

Comment: What command are you issueing? What version of the JVM do you have installed?

Comment: Also, what operating system? What machine? What architecture?  How much ram do you have?

Comment: Edited to include more info. Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: In a windows command prompt (Start > All programs > Accessories) type the following commands (without quotes) and include their output in your question please: 'java -version', 'echo %JAVA_HOME%' and 'echo %PATH%'

Comment: This error might occur because you invoke java by supplying the wrong arguments/options.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently, and found that the instructions [HERE](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html) fixed it.

In a nutshell, the instructions show  you how to make a System Variable for Java called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value `Xmx512M`. This sets a global maximum heap memory size for Java.

There was one caveat I noticed though. I noticed that if you start a Java application with a maximum heap memory size larger than the one set as the System Variable, you will get errors that stop the Java Virtual Machine from running.